# Write command in one terminal, see result on other one

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to run a command **foo** on one terminal and pass the result to another terminal. Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Also look into [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), both of which allow you to take over, mirror, or just execute commands on, other sessions.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, it is. A picture worth a thousand words:

[image: radu's terminal]

So, you have to redirect the output of your command using `>` operator to `/dev/pts/#`. You can find `#` using `who` or `w` command. If tou want to redirect and the errors, use:

```
<command> >& /dev/pts/#
```

Comment: thanks. but if the another terminal does not exist. what we should do? Or better to say pass it to newer one?

Comment: You will need probably a script to do that: the script will take as argument your command then should open a new `gnome-terminal` and detect the tty (using `tty` command) of the new terminal and finally send the output to it.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this for your `$HOME/.bashrc` :

```
ng() { gnome-terminal -x sh -c "$*; bash"; }
```

This will run a command and shows the result on a new terminal window.

Examples:

```
ng ls -l
ng echo foo
```

**Edit:** To consider aliases from the `$HOME/.bashrc` use this instead:

```
ng() { gnome-terminal -x bash -ic "$*; bash"; }
```

then the output of `ls` should be colored (thanks to Radu Rădeanu for this [hint](https://askubuntu.com/a/498718/265974)).

Comment: This will run the command directly in the new terminal.

Comment: Yes but what is the advantage to run it first in the old terminal ?

Comment: No advantage..., but in fact this answer to [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496914/write-command-in-one-terminal-see-result-on-other-one/496936?noredirect=1#comment665417_496919).

Comment: Ok there is a advantage with your method the output of `ls` is colored, don't know why this is not the case with my function...

Comment: You will understand if you will run `type ls` and then `ng type ls` :)

Comment: if write function in one line in bashrc, maybe need a semicolon to end it, or you will meet an "unexpected end of file" error.
so `ng() { gnome-terminal -x sh -c "$*; bash" ;}` should be better. And if you are using xfce(xfce4-terminal as default emulator): `ng() { xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$*; bash" ;}` or you can simply run by any default emulator `ng() { x-terminal-emulator -x sh -c "$*; bash";}`

Comment: @highwind thank you for the hint, I've changed it. But `x-terminal-emulator` didn't work for me.