# My .bashrc alias not run in .desktop file

Tags: .desktop, alias

I've added the following line to the `.bashrc` file:

```
alias midos="sh /home/erkanmdr/Belgeler/midos/midos.sh"
```

This command works fine in the terminal and tty.
But not working in my .desktop shortcut file.

midos.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MiDoS
Exec=midos
Icon=/home/erkanmdr/Belgeler/midos-128.png
Terminal=true
```

How do I execute my `midos` command in the .desktop shortcut file?

Comment: You can just substitute `Exec=midos` with `Exec=sh /home/erkanmdr/Belgeler/midos/midos.sh`

Comment: I do not want it. I want to use directly. Its possible?

Comment: I'd replace `sh` with `bash` (alias midos="bash /home/erkanmdr/Belgeler/midos/midos.sh")

Comment: @SylvainPineau not worked

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While the other answers offer a good workaround for your problem, to answer your question, the right way to use an alias inside a .desktop file is, in your case:

```
Exec=bash -ic "midos"
```

That's because aliases from `~/.bashrc` file will work *only*
 in a **bash interactive shell** (`-i` option is used in this case to start bash interactive).

If another user wants to use the same .desktop file, then he must to have defined as well that alias.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

I would be extremely surprised if the GUI has any idea about your shell. You should put the full path in your desktop file:

```
Exec=/home/erkanmdr/Belgeler/midos/midos.sh
```

And make sure that your script is executable.

Answer (score 6):

Little workaround.

Add this `#!/bin/bash` to the first line of your script, if it is not there already.

For example your script before:

```
sometext1
sometext2
sometext3
sometext4
```

You script after:

```
#!/bin/bash
sometext1
sometext2
sometext3
sometext4
```

Now copy your script to `/usr/local/bin`, and make it executable:

```
sudo cp /home/erkanmdr/Belgeler/midos/midos.sh /usr/local/bin/midos
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/midos
```

After that it should work as you want.