# Custom launcher not showing up in 'applications'

Tags: gnome, launcher, 14.10

I created a desktop launcher, to open Nautilus as root.

It does not show up in the activities search or in *All applications*.

How can I fix this?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files (Admin)
Comment=Access and organize files as root
Exec=gksudo nautilus %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;root;admin;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.1
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
```

Comment: Did you copy it into **`~/.local/share/applications`**?

Comment: Did you review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand ? *Why are you NOT using **eog.desktop** as a template?*

Comment: No I put it in /usr/share/applications

Comment: Not recommended. *Did you change ownership?* I tested from **.local** and it WORKS, under **14.04**.

Comment: Where do I find "eog.desktop"? Also when I create ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-admin.desktop and save it in gedit it becomes nautilus-admin.desktop.desktop. How can I stop the second desktop from being added? Do  I need to reboot to get it to work? I have found out how to stop the extra .desktop being added. I have the file there but gnome shell doesn't show it when I search

Comment: Read my response to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand *This method works for me.*

Comment: Hi. I did what you said in your response but it still doesn't show up

Comment: Ok... now I have a launcher that opens nautilus but not if I use gksudo, then it doesnt show up in gnome when I search for apps

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is Due to a Wrong or Missing Exec Command Path...
So Triple Check the Exec Command and Eventually Set the Absolute Path to the Binary.

Comment: it was useful for me but I want to add another surplus. If you deal with aliases (for instance in`~/.bash_aliases`) you must use the command introduced by [Radu Radeanu](https://askubuntu.com/a/498718/943483) : `Exec=bash -ic "alias_name"` instead of a simple `Exec=alias_name` in the `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm :-)

```
sudo cp ~/.local/share/applications/name.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this with an AppImage after swapping out the old image with the newly downloaded image. The issue was I hadn't marked the new image as executable yet.

```sh
chmod +x /path/to/new/appimage
```

After making the new image executable it was picked up after I logged back in.