# Output from commands in one terminator window displayed in another by default?

Tags: terminator

I have a split window setup for terminator and was wondering if there was a way to set it up such that the default is to run the commands from one window in the other.

I know that what I need to do is find a way to append `"> /dev/pts/17"` (my terminator window) to the end of every command. Is the way to do this by editing `.bashrc`?

Comment: This has been answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/496914/write-command-in-one-terminal-see-result-on-other-one .

Comment: So now I know that what I need to do is find a way to append "> /dev/pts/17" (my terminator window) to the end of every command. Is the way to do this by editing .bashrc?

Comment: You can do an `exec > /dev/pts/17` at the start of a shell.